# How to implement the Android CallLog TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Hey, I want to implement a view exactly like the callLog table layout.
Exactly like [this](http://the-gadgeteer.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/android-g1-42.jpg)

I´ve studied the documentation, but it didnt helped. because I want to print in a table layout a lot of data from the SQLite Database, so it must be generic, for all the retrieved data. But I cant.

If someone could show me the code that google uses on the Android CallLog List (for the TableLayout).

I need to know how to make the name of the contact bigger than the other texts, how to put the icon, etc.

thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hey, I want to implement a view exactly like the callLog table layout.

That is not a `TableLayout`. That is a `ListView`.

> If someone could show me the code that google uses on the Android CallLog List (for the TableLayout).

That is not a `TableLayout`. That is a `ListView`.

Android's source code is [here](http://source.android.com/). [Here is the source code to the Contacts application](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=tree), which includes the call log.